# Delayed immediate own answer accepting XOR own answer acceptance notification

Tags: feature-request, self-answer

Every now and then I ask a question only to find an answer myself a little later. Like [just now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8560571/41360). However I cannot accept my own answer until 48 hours have passed since I asked (or answered?) the question. That's understandable and reasonable. But also annoying, since I have to remember to revisit the question 2 days from now. This happens every once in a while, and more often than not I don't remember about it. Hence my acceptance rate suffers.

So here's two competing suggestions to tackle this:

1. If a question has no accepted answers 48 hours after asking AND there is an answer made by the author, send a notification to the author that he is free to accept his answer now;
2. Allow to tick the checkmark immediately, but show it with a dotted outline or something, meaning that it is "delayed accepted". This means that it is NOT YET accepted (others won't see it), but if there are no more answers within 48 hours, it will get accepted (so I don't need to revisit the question). If another answer is posted, the delayed-accepted status is removed and a typical notification is sent to my inbox. I can then review the new answer and either accept that immediately, or re-tick my own checkmark.

I'm not sure which one would be better from UI/UX point of view, but that's why people can comment this. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can just look through your asked questions and see which ones have a best answer selected and which ones don't. You can see from the picture below:

**white** means nothing was selected as best answer.

**yellow** means a best answer was selected.

[image]

Not being able to immediately accept your answer is a good thing in my opinion because what if someone is tediously working on answering your question, but after they finish they see you answer your own question with: "...I did this and fixed it".

If someone takes the time to answer your question and their answer was correct, I would rather give them the best answer than just give myself the credit for something that I should have thought over before asking for other peoples help.

Comment: I completely agree that it's a good thing. I have also re-accepted better answers that have come in much later. But I don't want to periodically go through my old questions to perform "housekeeping". That's why there are notifications - to notify you of action in your old questions.

Comment: @Vilx- I agree, it would be nice to get messages about your answers. But this would require some extra effort from the devs, and personally I don't think its that important...

Comment: Well, that will be up to them to decide. :) Personally I think that they give a comfortable UI a high priority, and this might fit with their agenda. But will see. :)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, but I have my reservations:

1. A notification implies that there even *is* an acceptable answer. I'd hate for someone to feel they have to choose an answer that may not be entirely correct because a notification told them to. The principle of the feature isn't groundless, perhaps there is a way to make it work, but I also don't see the huge payoff. Poor accept rate isn't a permanent blemish. You can go back and fix it.
2. This seems unnecessary, and while may not be confusing to you, may be more confusing to others. It also gives a "set it and forget it" feel. Let's say you ticked the "automatic mark as answer" box, and someone else provides an answer that's better than yours, maybe they thought of something significantly better. However, you'll have already forgotten to review the answers so it might never get noticed.

Low accept rate *is* your notification that you need to go back and mark some answers, yours or anyone elses.

If you find yourself posting a lot of questions then answering them yourself fairly quickly, perhaps you should put more effort into researching it before you make a question. Yes, [it's OK to answer your own question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but you are wasting your own time writing up a question and an answer.

Comment: 1. Personally I don't care about my acceptance rate, but there are some annoying people who like to point out all the time "Hey, your acceptance rate is only 59%! You should feel ashamed!" And, to be fair, there really are questions like that that I've missed.
2. The "Set and forget" feel was actually what I was aiming for. But there would be notifications (as usually when new answers are posted) that would make you go back and review.

Comment: "[Y]ou are wasting your own time"? That's a little harshly worded, I think.